# Accessing data in neighbor cells

Tags: c, nearest-neighbor, neighbours

I have a matrix `M` of size `m x n` which is saved as a one dimensional array `N` of length `m * n`. Every cell of this array contains some integer variables which are the ID of data points. The amount of integer variables in every cell changes over time.

```
N[0] = {1,4,5,7}
N[1] = {2,9,3,1,7,4}
N[2] = {7,1,3,9,8}
N[3] = {6,4,2}
...
```

I access these elements by using an index function which returns

`idx = x + y * n`

Given some index `idx` I want to use all integer variables of the neighbor cells and the central cell with index `idx` to access an array of data points `D` of size `s`. Size `s` can be very large.

To make my point clear: Instead of such a loop over all data points

```
for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
// Do something with D[i]
```

I want something like (but more compact)

```
// Access central cell
idx = x + y*n;
num_Elements = Number_of_Elements_Cell(x,y);
for(int i=0; i<num_Elements; i++)
// Do something with D[N[idx][i]]

// Access right cell
idx = (x+1) + y*n;
num_Elements = Number_of_Elements_Cell(x+1,y);
for(int i=0; i<num_Elements; i++)
// Do something with D[N[idx][i]]

// Access left cell
idx = (x-1) + y*n;
num_Elements = Number_of_Elements_Cell(x-1,y);
for(int i=0; i<num_Elements; i++)
// Do something with D[N[idx][i]]
```

and so on. For all cells I have to do that 9 times.

My question: Is there a better way to do that given the structure `N`?

Comment: and what's the problem? To implement `Number_of_Elements_Cell`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand your question well ....
but you could try :

```
for (int i=-1 ; i <= 1 ; i++){
    for (int j = -1 ; j <=1 ; j++){
        idx = (x+i) + (y+j)*n;
        // Check if idx is not out of bounds
        num_Elements = Number_of_Elements_Cell(x+i,y+j);
        for(int k=0; k<num_Elements; k++)
             // Do something with D[N[idx][k]]
    }
}
```

Note that your index could very well be out-of-bounds which such a method, so you'll have to implement a test to prevent that.

That's the way to simply iterate on a cell and its 8 neighbors using a double `for` loop.
If it's not what you expect, let me know, i'll edit/delete.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
var distinctDataPoints = new List<int>();
for(int z = x - 1, z <= x + 1, z++)
{
    if(z < 0 || z > m)
        continue;

    for(int t = y-1, t <= y + 1, t++)
    {   
        if(t < 0 || t > n)
            continue;

        idx = z + t * n;

        for(int i = 0; i < num_Elements; i++)
        {
            if(!distinctDataPoints.Contains(N[idx][i])
                distinctDataPoints.Add(N[idx][i])
        }
    }
}

for(int dpIdx = 0; dpIdx < distinctDataPoints.Count; dpIdx++)
{
    //Do something with D[dpIdx]
}
```